# How to average every two rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, row, average

I have the dataframe below of different volatilities over over different periods (3mth, 6mth, 9mth, 12mth) at different values (90%,100%,110%).  I however want to create the mean between each period group.  So for the 9mth values it would looke like:

9MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF = 19.53

**9MTH_IMPVOL_95%MNY_DF = 19.53**

9MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF = 18

**9MTH_IMPVOL_105%MNY_DF = 16.725**

9MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF = 15.45299

And so on for 12MTH values

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
 datestamp  entity        short_name                       item                     value source
   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                            <chr>                    <dbl> <chr> 
 1 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     23.9 PSEC  
 2 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF  18.0 PSEC  
 3 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    16.2 PSEC  
 4 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF    21.0 PSEC  
 5 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18   PSEC  
 6 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_110.0%MNY_DF  15.8 PSEC  
 7 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     21.5 PSEC  
 8 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF   18.5 PSEC  
 9 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    15.0 PSEC  
10 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_90.0%MNY_DF   22.0 PSEC  
11 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18.3 PSEC  
12 2006-01-03 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF   16.7 PSEC  
13 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     23.9 PSEC  
14 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF  18.0 PSEC  
15 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    16.2 PSEC  
16 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF    21.0 PSEC  
17 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18   PSEC  
18 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_110.0%MNY_DF  15.8 PSEC  
19 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     21.5 PSEC  
20 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF   18.5 PSEC  
21 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    15.0 PSEC  
22 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_90.0%MNY_DF   22.0 PSEC  
23 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18.3 PSEC  
24 2006-01-04 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF   16.7 PSEC  
25 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     23.9 PSEC  
26 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF  18.0 PSEC  
27 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    16.2 PSEC  
28 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF    21.0 PSEC  
29 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18   PSEC  
30 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_110.0%MNY_DF  15.8 PSEC  
31 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     21.5 PSEC  
32 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF   18.5 PSEC  
33 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    15.0 PSEC  
34 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_90.0%MNY_DF   22.0 PSEC  
35 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_100%MNY_DF    18.3 PSEC  
36 2006-01-05 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF   16.7 PSEC  
37 2006-01-06 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 3MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF     23.8 PSEC  
38 2006-01-06 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 6MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF  18.1 PSEC  
39 2006-01-06 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 9MTH_IMPVOL_110%MNY_DF    16.2 PSEC  
40 2006-01-06 JALSHTR Index FTSE/JSE Africa All Shares Index 12MTH_IMPVOL_90%MNY_DF    21.0 PSEC
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Seem like a probably duplicate of the FAQ [How to calculate mean by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061) I'd recommend the `dplyr`-based solution for a new user.